# How To: Notepad++ From Linebreaks to commas

Tags: notepad++

I want to make this solution in Notepad++:

**BEFORE:**
this is a sample text
this is a sample text
this is a sample text
this is a sample text

**AFTER:**
this is a sample text, this is a sample text, this is a sample text, this is a sample text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Ctrl/H.

In the 'Search Mode' box, choose 'Extended'.

In the 'Find what' box, fill `\r\n`.

In the 'Replace with' box, fill `,` (space after the comma).

Click 'Replace All'.

Answer (score 1):

In the replacement dialog, check "regular expression"

Find what: `\r\n`

Replace with: `,`   (that's comma-space)

Comment: You can also use the "Extended Mode"

Comment: The output is not what I want it to be.. it should be continuos and then no newline breaks... should be: SAMPLE, SAMPLE, SAMPLE, SAMPLE

Comment: @user3126697 See @barak manos answer - try changing `\n` to `\r\n`

Comment: The solution you gave will only put , before the text.. should be the same output I posted above

Comment: Grumble grumble `\r` grumble grumble fixed grumble grumble mumble grumble.